# How to set time interval for UIDatePickerView?

Tags: ios, objective-c, uidatepicker

I am setting time interval for `UIDatePickerView` is 30 minutes and getting exactly. But my doubt is when I am setting `minimumDate` for `UIDatePickerView` is `[NSDate date]` where current time is 04:25. Then `minimumDate` is setting 04:00. But I want as 04:30.
My code is

```
 datePicker.datePickerMode = UIDatePickerModeDateAndTime;
 datePicker.minuteInterval = 30;
datePicker.minimumDate = [NSDate date];
datePicker.maximumDate = [[NSDate date]dateByAddingTimeInterval:32*60*60];
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
datePicker.datePickerMode = UIDatePickerModeDateAndTime;
datePicker.minuteInterval = 30;
datePicker.minimumDate = [[NSDate date] dateByAddingTimeInterval:30*60];
datePicker.maximumDate = [[NSDate date] dateByAddingTimeInterval:(32*60*60 + 30*60)];
```